# SSIS Package not running from server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl, script-task

I have an SSIS package that does the following;

1. Detects if a file (excel exists)
2. Deletes file
3. Copies file from a directory into the required one

This package when run locally to test functions correctly there are no issues.

When running on server or as a job I get the error of

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I believe the error to be based around the copy code line, as commenting this out still allows the package to run.

My version of Visual Studio is 2013 (unable to upgrade) and the SQL-Server machine is running the latest version of 2016.

The account used to run the job is considered a network administrator - the error persists.

```
Imports System.IO (etc)

Public Sub Main()
        Dim sourcePath As String = "\\server\File\Template.xlsx"
        Dim destPath As String = "\\server\File\NewFile.xlsx"


        If File.Exists(destPath) = True Then
            File.Delete(destPath)       'deletes current file
        End If
        File.Copy(sourcePath, destPath)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

I wouldn't expect any issues doing this, as other packages (different functions etc.) work as they should.

Comment: Why are you using a Script Task to do the movement of the file and not a File System Task? You'll need to add error handling into your Script Task to find out the problem, and expose the error; then you can find out the error in the SSISDB logs. Or you could use a File System Task.

Comment: Wait... *"My version of Visual Studio is 2013 (unable to upgrade) and the SQL-Server machine is running the latest version of 2016."* SSDT for VS 2013 doesn't support SQL Server 2016; you *need* to use a more recent version.

Comment: The end goal is to dynamically name the file to the current date/time. I'm not fully aware if theres another way to dynamically rename files is that way.

Unfortunatly, upgrading isnt an option to due legacy items - I have no say in our upgrade process unfortunatly.

Comment: *"The end goal is to dynamically name the file to the current date/time. I'm not fully aware if theres another way to dynamically rename files is that way."* Why haven't used considered using a variable?

Comment: A lack of knowldge. I'll do some digging as to it's suitability. Thank you

Comment: Beside Larnu said, come back to this problem, have you check Network administrator have access to the folder that you copy to?

Comment: BeiBei ZHU - Myself and the account for SQL Agent have access. 

Is there a foolproof way to verify what user is being used the job when running a job and when executing a ssis package from server?

Comment: Check this related question to identify the real error cause, since the error message you provided is generic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299342/error-0x1-at-xx-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

This is a generic Script task message. Pretty standard suggestion: consider capturing a real exception text for a better issue analysis via `FireError`:

```
Imports System.IO (etc)

Public Sub Main()
Try

    Dim sourcePath As String = "\\server\File\Template.xlsx"
    Dim destPath As String = "\\server\File\NewFile.xlsx"

    If File.Exists(destPath) = True Then
    File.Delete(destPath)       'deletes current file
    End If
    File.Copy(sourcePath, destPath)


Catch ex As Exception
   Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script Task Example", ex.Message, String.Empty, 0);  
End Try

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
```

There are plenty of reasons for such code to fail, one of them is related to an in-place package upgrade which didn't upgrade a script task to VSTA 2015 correctly.

Comment: Thank you - I'll look at it from this direction. Wasnt aware of FireError.

Comment: Due to version differences between Visual Studio and the Server - this wont work.

Comment: @user2261755, the usage of `try..catch` to capture a real error message is something  that should work in all versions of SSIS

Answer (score 0):

The error exists due to versioning differences between the SSIS Package writtne in Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2016.

Upgrade errros can be found within the message portion of the error report.