# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation - While executing a .dtsx file in Visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I have developed an ssis package and i have a script which fetches few text command from a .txt file , stores those in variables and i use those variables to see what to do next and which dft to execute.

When i go to the .dtsx file--> right click--> execute -->i get the error message saying "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

[image]

However when i stop running the package and try to re execute it it runs successfully.

I tried to deploy this to the Integration Services Catalogs and it throws the same error which i see in the report files

> Script task error: exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

`varERMLoadTxt` hold the text file path which stream reader reads

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            string path = Dts.Variables["User::varERMLoadTxt"].Value.ToString();
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                string line = File.ReadAllText(path);
                string[] lines = line.Split(',');
                if(lines[0].Equals("load", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                Dts.Variables["User::varIsLoad"].Value = true;
                else if (lines[0].Equals("update", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    Dts.Variables["User::varIsUpdate"].Value = true;
                Dts.Variables["User::varCommand"].Value = lines[0].ToString();
                Dts.Variables["User::varAnalysisDate"].Value = lines[1].ToString();
                sr.Close();



            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

enum ScriptResults
{
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
};
```

Comment: Just set a break point in your script, run your package and step through it to see where exactly what's going on.

Comment: Did you already check you set all variables you're using to be accessible by your Script Task?

Comment: yes everything is accessible .. because one time it runs fine in Visual studio and one time it gives this error..

Comment: the main problem is its very unpredictable of when its failing..i have tried three times now with break point but it passed ..i am so confused of what to do

Comment: its not at all failing when i debug.. but its giving that error pop up now and then when i run that without  debugger

Comment: Could it be that the file you are trying to write to is locked somehow? Please check if the stack trace shown in your screenshot is complete - preferably copy-n-paste the text here in your post.

Comment: yes this is the complete stack trace that was in the link to the picture.. if the file will be in locked state then why is it not failing in debugging ?

Comment: One thing I'd change is replacing the string variable for the path by a File Connection. Other than that you could just comment out everything except the opening and closing of the file stream to see what happens.

Comment: by file connection do you mean "System.IO.File.ReadAllText" and passing the path directly instead of the variable?

Comment: actually the file is in a shared path...(\\azr01fsxxx\azr10devyyy\ggg\hhh\Inbox\ERM.txt)

Comment: Have a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52653538/10376537 shows how to wrap your code in a try-catch so it returns back to ssis a more meaningful error message.

Comment: By File Connection I mean a Package or Project configured File Connection like you would configure a database connection. It is then explicitly made accessible for your Script Task and provides methods for explicitly acquiring and releasing this connection and use it's path information. With the file actually residing on a network share there's added potential for failure. From what your code shows, this file contains some processing signals that might be simpler to store and share in a database. Maybe add some context so people can suggest a more reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 suggestions:

1. Use a try ... catch block and Dts.FireError method to read the real exception:

- [Error: 0x1 at XX: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299342/error-0x1-at-xx-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation/56299990#56299990)

2. Check if the file exists before opening it
3. Check that variables names are correct *(note that variable names are case sensitive)*

*The whole code should looks like*

```cs
public void Main()
        {
        try{    

                string path = Dts.Variables["User::varERMLoadTxt"].Value.ToString();
            
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
                {
                string line = File.ReadAllText(path);
                    string[] lines = line.Split(',');
    
                    if(lines[0].Equals("load", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                        Dts.Variables["User::varIsLoad"].Value = true;
                else if (lines[0].Equals("update", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    Dts.Variables["User::varIsUpdate"].Value = true;
                
            Dts.Variables["User::varCommand"].Value = lines[0].ToString();
                    Dts.Variables["User::varAnalysisDate"].Value = lines[1].ToString();
                    sr.Close();
                     }
            }   

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;    

        }catch(Exception ex){

            Dts.FireError(0,"An error occured", ex.Message,String.Empty, 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
 
            }

        }

enum ScriptResults
{
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
};
```